# response header has encoding error on python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Some http response header without English (using utf-8) has encoding error.
original text (2. 핵심정보를 담은 발표 형성평가 5월 19일) I uploaded this text on server.

and I responded to server with get function. (`requests.get()`)
but I got this text (2. íµì¬ì ë³´ë¥¼ ë´ì ë°í íì±íê° 5ì 19ì¼) from http response header.

I converted the text has encoding error to ascii to utf8 converter. It converts successfully.
maybe requests package gets http response header with ascii encoding.

**EDIT**

I tried this code `req.encoding = 'utf-8'` but this code didn't work.

code:

```
headers = {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
            'Content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
        }

        req = requests.get(link, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
        req.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(req.headers['Content-Disposition']) # this code prints the text has encoding error
```

**Also you can view my issue on github python requests https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5463 )**

Comment: whats the actual `url` so we can try it out?

Comment: @Tarique Actually, you have to know send-anywhere.
because I'm making API for send-anywhere.

To get URL, you have to send a file from [send-anywhere](http://www.send-anywhere.com)
and write the number and get link using this program ( go to [my github repo](https://github.com/MineEric64/SendAnywhere-for-Python) and run test-for-requests.py

sorry

you can tell me if you don't know to use send-anywhere. I will tell you how to send a file from send-anywhere.

Comment: @Tarique Thank you. but I fixed now.
you can view how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER**

`text.encode("ISO-8859-1").decode("utf-8")`

I just fixed it.
I had to encode with ISO-8859-1 and decode with utf-8.

Comment: useful, worked with python3.6.4 and requests=2.21.0, win64 default codepage 936. I was using requests to download file, and when trying to get file name from response headers, I only got some unreadable text. I don't know why this happens, but re-encode the text with iso8859-1 fixed the problem. May be the requests library doesn't treat the response headers properly and mis-decode it using iso8859-1?